# Is there any transversal logical $CNOT$ (or $CZ$), not involving all the physical qubits?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Well-known codes, such as Shor's code or the CSS [[7,1,3]], allows for transversal implementation of logical $CNOT$.

On the other hand, there are codes, such as the prefect code [[5,1,3]], for which the logical $CNOT$ must be non-transversal, but they do not involve all the physical qubits.

I wonder whether there exists something in the middle. Specifically, a code admitting a transversal implementation of logical $CNOT$ (or $CZ$), but not necessarily involving all the physical qubits.